# Delphi - unit segregation

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

My new component (TComponent) uses DsgnIntf since I use custom property editors. The problem is when using the component in a custom VCL application - DSGNINTF.DCU not found! One solution is to add a command line switch to a compiler (dont remember any more what is it), but I don't like that solution. The second solution is a unit segregation. I found this:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27717

The problem is - I don't understand this article so well.. I don't know what exactly I need to do in my component unit to separate design-time from runtime code. Could someone please make the simplest example and explain it? I just want to avoid problems with "dsgnintf.dcu not found" when people using my component. Thank you.

EDIT: 
I looked the article a bit more and I realize the second unit registers the first one. To avoid dsgnintf.dcu problem I presume the second unit must be in it's own .pas file?

Comment: The article you link to is all you need.

Comment: I agree with David Heffernan. The example there, with separate `MixedComponent` and `MixedComponentReg` units, should already be clear. (Notice how `MixedComponent` doesn't use `DesignIntf`? Applications that use the component only include `MixedComponent`, not `MixedComponentReg`, so they don't need `DesignIntf`.) If you have specific questions, could you edit your question to clarify what bits you don't understand?

Comment: the second unit is commonly in its own Package (.dpk) file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you create a single unit to register your package in IDE, something like that:

```
unit RegPackage;

interface

uses
  Classes, MyUnit;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyPage', [TMyComponent]);
end;

end.
```

and include this unit into design-only package:

```
package MyPackD;

{$R *.res}
..

requires
  rtl, MyPackR; // your runtime package

contains
  RegPackage in 'RegPackage.pas';

end.
```

The article you link covers also property editors. All package code not related to IDE should be contained in run-only package:

```
package MyPackR;

{$R *.res}
..

requires
  rtl,
  vcl;

contains
  MyUnit in 'MyUnit.pas';

end.
```

Comment: Thanks. This explains a bit what I needed.

Comment: +1, though I'd rather say "All package code related to IDE should be contained in design-only package". Semantics...

Comment: @GolezTrol - the point is what should be in `requires` and `containes` clauses. Design package contains all IDE-related code and requires runtime package.

Answer (score 3):

You must separate your run-time code and design-time code into separate packages.  Create a runtime-only package that contains just your component code.  Create a designtime-only package that specifies your runtime-only package and the IDE's `DesignIDE` package in its `requires` list, and contains just your property editor and registration code.  Then you can install the designtime-only package into the IDE, and refer to the runtime-only package in your projects.  The `DesignIDE` package resolves the `DsgnInf` reference, but it is **NOT** allowed to be linked into runtime executables! It is for the IDE's use only.